# Angular 6 running component scripts priorly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a large HTML table scrolling horizontally and executing logic to fill the background of each cell. Testing in production (ng builg --prod) on a server, I have noticed that on each scroll some scripts are executed and it leads to small amount of lagging after each scroll movement.

See picture below:

[image: Chrome 68 performance profile - large HTML Table scroll with scripts]
Is there a way to tell Angular to finish rendering and executing scripts first before displaying the component?

(Using Angular 6, Chrome 68)

Comment: this might help? https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks .. maybe ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help because ngOnInit and/or ngAfterViewInit is triggered once per component load and that's it. What I found out is that the scripts executed in above picture are zones and are triggered by Angular's default change detection.